# How to setup daily SQL server export to csv text file?

Tags: sql-server, export

We are exporting 100,000+ rows from a SQL Server 2005 DB to a text file. We have a web script setup to read all rows and then write the text file and it takes over 5 minutes to complete that script.

How can we set it up to export directly from SQL server to a csv file and schedule that daily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, no problem.  Use BCP (which is a command line tool) to export the data.  Once you have the parameters the way you like, schedule this as a SQL Agent job.